# MQ Extended Transactional Client

Tags: ibm-mq

Is Extended Transactional Client installed by default? How do I verify if this is installed or not? How do I get this installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In previous versions of the MQ client, it certainly wasn't included with the standard client (the Transactional Client had cost / licensing implications).

However from the date of the announcement of WMQ v7.5 onwards it is now included with the Standard clients at v7.0.1 and up.

From the [IBM Websphere site](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/clients/)

> With the availability of WebSphere MQ V7.5 the capability previously
>   delivered within the Extended Transactional Client is incorporated
>   into the standard WebSphere MQ client.

And in more detail, [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/1/897/ENUS212-091/index.html&lang=en&request_locale=en)

> Wider access to the Extended Transactional Client for all customers
>   The Extended Transactional Client enables customers to configure their
>   WebSphere MQ client to participate in a transactional unit of work
>   when exchanging messages to an MQ server. Use of this client without
>   charge was previously restricted to customers using WebSphere
>   Application Server, WebSphere Enterprise Service Bus, or WebSphere
>   Process Server as the Transaction Manager. With the announcement of
>   WebSphere MQ V7.5, the Extended Transactional Client is available for
>   use in all client deployments without additional entitlement. This
>   includes all supported versions of WebSphere MQ client connecting to
>   any supported version of WebSphere MQ queue manager.
>
> With the availability of WebSphere MQ V7.5 the capability previously
>   delivered within the Extended Transactional Client is incorporated
>   into the standard WebSphere MQ client. Customers using WebSphere MQ
>   V7.0.1 and WebSphere MQ V7.1 gain the benefit of use of the Extended
>   Transactional Client without charge from the date of this
>   announcement. IBM is making available refreshed code including updated
>   License Information. Customers can realize this benefit through the
>   download and acceptance of this new License Information.

Answer (score 2):

The XTC component used to be provided separately with the queue manager and required both a license and a separate install step.  As of this year, it is free and built into the client.  All of the client software downloads have been updated with the XTC capabilities and there is no longer a separate component.  To obtain it, just download and install the latest client.  Recommended to use the v7.5 client if at all possible but everything from v7.0 and up is available and supported.

- V7.0 - [SupportPac MQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7)
- V7.1 - [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71)
- V7.5 - [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75)

Comment: Absolutely. I usually recommend using the latest client for new development.  Since clients are forward and backward compatible with the QMgr, the V7.5 client will work with V7.1 QMgr now, and then down the road v7.6 or v8.0, whatever number the use for the next release. Please see [Compatibility between different versions of a WebSphere MQ MQI client and a queue manager](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/mi23004_.htm).  Basically, it says any client works with any version QMgr but you are limited to functionality of the earliest version in the combo.